# How do you generate a backlash signal for simple sine wave input using python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the below python codes so as to generate the 
    backlash signal for a simple sine wave input.The generated 
    output is not as per the requirement.The output should be
    similar to that of backlash block used in Simulink.

```
#Importing libraries 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Setting upper limit and lower limit
LL = -0.5
UL = 0.5

#Generating the sine wave
x=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
y=(np.sin(x))

#phase shift of y1 by -pi/2
y1=(np.sin(x-1.571))

# plot original sine
plt.plot(x,y)

#setting the thresholds 
y1[(y1>UL)] = UL
y1[(y1<LL)] = LL

#Initializing at the input
y1[(y==0)]  = 0

y1[(y1>UL)] -= UL
y1[(y1<LL)] -= LL

#Plotting both the waves
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y1)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please refer the image attached.The output should be similar as mentioned in the image.

Comment: Please provide the other piece to the puzzle. We need to see both what you get and what you expect.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: I am getting the output as shown in the second image.This doesn't  meet the requirement.The first image [above] is the required and the image below [second one] is what I am getting as output.The output has to follow the input after crossing over the thresholds as shown in the first image [above].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple vectorized implementation for the backlash process.  The k-th output depends on the previous values in a nontrivial way. A concise way to write the process (assuming `x` is the input array and `y` is the output array) is

```
y[k] = min(max(y[k-1], x[k] - h), x[k] + h)
```

where `h` is half the deadband.

The following script includes a `backlash` function that uses a Python for-loop.  (The function uses `if` statements instead of the `min` and `max` functions.)  It is simple, but it won't be very fast.  If high performance is important, you might consider reimplementing the function in [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

```
import numpy as np


def backlash(x, deadband=1.0, initial=0.0):
    """
    Backlash process.

    This function emulates the Backlash block of Simulink
    (https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/backlash.html).

    x must be a one-dimensional numpy array (or array-like).
    deadband must be a nonnegative scalar.
    initial must be a scalar.
    """
    halfband = 0.5*deadband

    y = np.empty_like(x, dtype=np.float64)
    current_y = initial

    for k in range(len(x)):
        current_x = x[k]
        xminus = current_x - halfband
        if xminus > current_y:
            current_y = xminus
        else:
            xplus = current_x + halfband
            if xplus < current_y:
                current_y = xplus
        y[k] = current_y

    return y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
    x = np.sin(t)
    deadband = 1
    y = backlash(x, deadband=deadband)

    plt.plot(t, x, label='x(t)')
    plt.plot(t, y, '--', label='backlash(x(t))')
    plt.xlabel('t')

    plt.legend(framealpha=1, shadow=True)
    plt.grid(alpha=0.5)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Update: I implemented the `backlash` function as a NumPy [gufunc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html) in my [ufunclab repository](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/ufunclab).

Comment: Truly an Engineering answer.The vectorisation is bit difficult for this output signal and then following the input signal with a delay/lag for certain time step. +1 Vote for your answer.